# fade / velocity with window.onload not working in 50% of all pageloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Same problem as many have - I used a preloader with jquery fadeOut and it stutters a bit (Firefox) and on my mobile or Chromium it did not "fire" in ~50% of all pageloads at all.

Now I have exchanged it with .velocity, same result.

Works fine in Firefox, just a little stuttering on some subpages - but its a horror to see this in Chrome or on my mobile - in 50% of all pageloads there is no fade-effect at all, it just "jumps" from invisible to visible immediately.

I already tried around by adding

```
{
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    transform: translatez(0);
}
```

to many classes with the same result. I am using it this way

```
    // Wait until all images loaded
        window.onload=function() {
    // Fade
        $(".jtpl-logo").velocity("fadeOut", {delay:50, duration: 400});  
        $(".jtpl-navigation-label").delay(900).velocity({ opacity: 1 }, 600);
};
```

Directly before this I run a

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".jtpl-background-area").css('-webkit-animation', 'fadein 5s');
});
```

I know its not so good to run both at the same time, but it makes no difference if I disable the background-fadeIn on $(document).ready running at the same time - the fadeOut of the white "preloader-page" with fadeOut at window.onload makes exactly the same problems.

So the problem is anything else - but what?

I have to use it on window.onload, if I use it on $(document).ready some page-elements are still not ready.

Need ideas how to solve this, give me some input please. Why is it not firing in 50% of all cases with Chrome or jumping so heavily? Is there any good option for jquery or velocity to ensure that the fade works in 100% of all pageloads?

Any idea to improve this is welcome. Many thanks already

Comment: CSS animations don't work when the browser is loading. I think this might be your problem.

Comment: You can read a little about this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706848/showing-a-css-loading-indicator-while-fetching-data